# Diagnosing RAM being damaged by other hardware

Tags: memory, hardware-failure

About a year ago I had trouble with some bad memory as discussed in my previous [question](https://superuser.com/questions/686206/diagnosing-random-computer-crashes).  After that I replaced all 4 of my RAM sticks which solved the issue.

About a week ago the issue re-appeared.  I just confirmed that it is again a faulty RAM stick using 2 passes of memtest86+.  Since this is the second time this has happened, I am fairly certain something else is damaging the RAM very slowly.  My question is, what could be damaging it and how can I diagnose it?  My guess would be either the motherboard or power supply, but nothing else appears to be hurt so is my best bet simply to replace the mother board when I buy new RAM?

EDIT:
Some more information regarding the memory failures.  In the first instance of memory failures, 2 of the 4 modules failed, but I replaced them all since I upgraded from 8 to 16GB at the time.  So far this time 2 (and perhaps 3) of the modules survived.  The module that I have confirmed failed this time was in a slot that survived the last time.  The fourth modules is getting passes in memtest86+ as I write this.

The air temp inside my case sits around 35 C, and MemTest86+ says my CPU temp sits around 70 C when it is running, although it may be higher with windows.  I don't believe it is a temperature issue.

Comment: Nothing really could unless your overclocking it.

Comment: My motherboard is capable of overclocking but I have never touched any of those settings.

Comment: Is the environment your machine is kept dusty, humid or susceptible to power fluctuations?

Comment: It just sits in my bedroom and is powered through a surge protector.  The inside of the case is mildly dusty, but all of the heatsinks and fan filters look reasonably clean.  Also the computer is powered down at night and when I'm at work, so it's not sitting around idling with the chance to overheat or anything.

Comment: Any two points will form a line . . .

Comment: That is true, but I would much prefer spending a day or two to check things than buying more RAM a year from now.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't trying to be flippant . . . my point is that new RAM is the easiest/cheapest solution.  If you've got an intermittent hardware issue that manifests once a year, it's unlikely you'll be able to reproduce it or isolate it.  You didn't mention in your first post if you tested the new memory once you put it in - for all you know, the issue could have still been there, implying it was the memory controller, and not the memory modules . . .

Comment: I don't think I tested the new RAM when I got it, and if I did, I no longer have the results for it.  I know that the last time, only two of the four sticks failed.  Once I started having issued though, the computer crashes every 30-60 min and stops if I remove the damaged stick(s).  The current problem is the damaged RAM, but it just seems odd to me that I've had two sets of RAM fail in the same setup after 1-2 years of running.  I realize that diagnosing this problem is a shot in the dark.

Comment: A me-2. I have recently had the same issue, perfect operation for years, then tiny intermittent fail when run at speed. Things to note: The cpu is now the ram controller, cpu socket pin connection way more critical, and power is regulated by the motherboards, even interference issues are said to be possible. All I have so far is the ram (mine) itself does not work the same as it did , in the new motherboard even, same PSU, the replacement ram is working fine today, and in either motherboard. This is what I found only for me, after never having a ram chunk go bad in 20years before.

Comment: If you really want to isolate, I'd first verify the memory in another system, which should point towards whether it's the controller/memory slots/etc or the modules themselves . . .

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't had any spikes in power, you're not over clocking and your computer is relatively dust free and operating under a reasonable temperature then there seems to be two possible causes.

1. You hit the jackpot and got multiple sticks of bad ram in successive purchases.  These defects don't always appear immediately and can manifest over time.
2. A slot on the motherboard is defective causing the ram to perform incorrectly and over time, destroying it.

You mentioned that last time you replaced all sticks of ram and it solved the problem, does that mean you ran a test and all of them were corrupt? Just replace the bad stick you have now, note the slot and either put a new stick in there or shuffle the ram around so you're using that slot again.  If another stick goes bad there you know that it is most likely that slot.

Comment: I added more information to the question regarding temperatures and which modules failed each time.